# Python Flask MySQL, problem with UPDATE query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, cgi

I just started using Python for a new project and I would like some help on a very irritating issue.

Environment[Python, Flask, MySQL]
I am currently developing a Web Application (login, user information management, survey form)

When the user first register on the application, username, password, mail address are inserted into the DB.
Also, since I need to record every answer given to the survey form, I automatically assign a 0 value to Q001 and Q002 (questions).

Once loggedin, the user will start answering the survey and I want those answers, and those answers only, to replace the value inside the corresponding row.
I was trying to use the UPDATE SET WHERE query but I keep getting a "not enough arguments for format string" error.
This is the python code

```
poll_data = {
   'question1' : 'Are you a donkey?',
    'question2' : 'Are you a pig?',
} 
@app.route('/flaskProject/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Output message if something goes wrong...
    msg = ''
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        Q001 = 0
        Q002 = 0
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', (username,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists!'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
        else:
            # Account doesn't exists and the form data is valid, now insert new account into accounts table
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (username, password, email, Q001, Q002, ))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered!'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html', msg=msg)   
@app.route("/flaskProject/questionnaire1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def questionnaire1():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'loggedin' in session:
        # Create variables for easy access
        Q001 = request.form['Q001']
        Q002 = request.form['Q002']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("UPDATE accounts SET Q001 = %s, Q002 = %s WHERE id = %s", (session['id'],))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        # Redirect to survey
    return render_template('questionnaire1.html', data=poll_data)
```

below is my BD

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `flaskProject` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `flaskProject`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    'Q001' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    'Q002' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, 'Q001', 'Q002') VALUES (1, 'test', 'test', 'test@test.com', '0', '0');
```

and finally the html of the survey page

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('questionnaire1') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ data.question1 }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
        <label for="Q001"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Q001" placeholder="Q001" id="Q001" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ data.question2 }}</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
        <label for="Q002"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Q002" placeholder="Q002" id="Q002" required></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
        <div class="msg">{{ msg }}</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every placeholder -- `%s` -- in your query, you need to supply a variable in the tuple that is the 2nd argument to `.execute()`.

You have the variables you need, you're just not supplying them yet.

Change the `UPDATE` query line to:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE accounts SET Q001 = %s, Q002 = %s WHERE id = %s", 
               (Q001, Q002, session['id'],))
```

...and you should be back on track.

Comment: That solved the problem entirely. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Absolutely, and thanks for accepting the answer. Best wishes with the rest of the project :)